# Specific NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception

i have short question, tell me just why first example don't work and second works.
Code before examples:

```
Tiles[] myTiles = new Tile[23];
number = 1;
```

First Example:

```
for(Tile tile : this.myTiles) {
    if (number != this.myTiles.length) {
        tile = new Tile(number, getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_default));
        number++;
    }
}
```

Second Example:

```
for(Tile tile : this.myTiles) {
    if (number != this.myTiles.length){
        this.myTiles[number-1] = new Tile(number, getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_default));
        number++;
    }
}
```

If i use code below in other method in class

```
this.myTiles[0].getNumber();
```

It's NullPointerException.
But with Second Example it nicely works.

I really don't know why. Thanks for any response

Comment: Because your first for loop is not modifying the object in your array.

Comment: tile in first example is not refference to object in my array?

Comment: what type is `myTiles`

Comment: @user2899587 No. See this: http://ideone.com/j6a0mc

Comment: what is the predefined value of number in second loop

Comment: i edited. myTiles are Tile[] and number is 1

Comment: It might be easier to explain if someone drew a diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop makes a copy of each object and is equivalent to

```
for (int i=0; i < myTiles.length; i++) {
   Tile tile;
   ...
   tile = new Tile(...); // set local reference only
}
```

As elements in an Object array are `null` by default these would remain unassigned outside the scope of the loop. The original elements of the `myTiles` remain at their default `null` values

Comment: Why it's just make only copy, tile is refference to object in array myTiles.

Comment: The enhanced for loop creates a local reference which is not assigned to any of the array elements

Answer (score 1):

The for each loop uses an `Iterator` internally to fetch items from the collection and return you a new reference to a local variable containing each element - overwriting this reference is completely useless, as it is only valid for one for-loop and will be replaced on the next.

"Internally", your first loop would translate to

```
for (Iterator<Tile> iterator = myTiles.iterator(); iterator.hasNext;){
    Tile tile = iterator.next();
    tile = new Tile(number, getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_default));
    number++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is no such thing as manipulating a pointer directly. Any time you get a reference to an object, you are getting a copy to a reference, like a pointer to a pointer. For this reason if you do something like:

```
String s = "hello";
modify(s);
System.out.println(s); // still hello!

void modify(String s){
  s = s + " world";
}
```

You can't actually change the original reference `s` because the function is manipulating a copy to that reference. In the example above you would need something like this:

```
String s = "hello";
s = modify(s);
System.out.println(s); // prints 'hello world'

String modify(String s){
  return s + " world";
}
```

The same happens in your for comprehension. The variable `tile` is bound to the loop and is a copy of a reference in the array. The original reference (the array at the given position) can't be changed directly this way. That's why you need to call directly:

```
myTiles[i] = // something
```

Read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html) for more information.

So the idiomatic way of modifying an array in java is something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myTiles.length; i++){
  myTiles[i] = new Tile(...); // directly reassigning the reference in the array!
}
```